# Fetch page values dynamically?

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.  We are running an .NET e-commerce website via nopCommerce 3.5 and would like to enable Google remarketing code fully.  We included the Google remarketing code BUT it is static - i.e we put it in on the header of the site and it works - its in every page BUT it is hard coded and refers to a single item on our site.

I am trying to work out how to make the remarketing code dynamic.  I.e each page would fetch its own values dynamically via .NET or SQL.

Google remarketing code is looking for:

1. `ecomm_prodid: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',`
   (I think this is a product id)
2. `ecomm_pagetype: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',`
   (I think this is page type)
3. `ecomm_totalvalue: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',`
   (I think this is total value)

How would I get each product page to retrieve 3 values and place them on the product page instead of `REPLACE_WITH_VALUE`? (Even if its only one - the product ID)?

[image: Screenshot]

We have an awful lot of products on our site, but maybe I could manually code in the best sellers.  I don't know to go about this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you don't want to do it yourself, there appears to be a plugin for that. Did you take a look at it? http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/nc/Google+Analytics+or+Universal+Analytics+Plugin

Comment: hi, i was looking but did not see this plugin before.  Will it generate the ecomm_prodid etc code on each page?

Comment: It looks like it generates code for views and conversions

Comment: hi, i checked our nopcommerce... we have google analytics like the above but we don't have google re marketing.  i don't think there is a plugin.  it would have to be done in asp.net

Comment: So no easy way out then. Checking the sources at https://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Models/Catalog/ProductDetailsModel.cs, the `ProductDetailModel` has a submodel `AddToCartModel` which in turn has a member `ProductId`. You should be able to use this field to fill you GA variable with it, like this: `ecomm_prodid:'<%#this.AddToCart.ProductId%>';`

Comment: cool.. do you think it could be something short like ecomm_prodid:'<%#this.AddToCart.ProductId%> ? do i have to do any other mvc to retrieve productID ?

Comment: Provided you use it in the correct place (a page that uses the productDetailModel) - that's it. You can also get the price in a similar manner: `ecomm_totalvalue:'<%#this.ProductPrice.Price%>';`

Comment: Great stuff ! ecomm_prodid:'<%#this.AddToCart.ProductId%>' is Product Id.  But is %#this.ProductPrice.Price% = pagetype ?  The last one is total value.. I saw ProductPrice but I'm not sure

Comment: Sorry i have no idea what to put in pagetype, since this might be more of a business decision. You could just put "productdetail" as a static value or something depending on the product shown.

Comment: Yes, its marketing so I'm not sure either.  page type sounds like some kind of category the user is looking at:S  But at least the 3rd value should be straightforward... the product price... but i didn't see it

Comment: our site is www.northseaworkwear.com.  I was looking at the code on page with a product here:    !--price & add to cart-->

<div class="prices" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <div class="product-price">

            <span   itemprop="price" class="price-value-328"   >
€91.52 incl tax            </span>
        </div>
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
</div> ............Can product-price be used for the price ?

Comment: I put the code for price in the 7th comment. Looking at the rendered page is not much use, you'll have to try it out.

Comment: I hope it works, write another comment if it doesnt. I also added this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the nopcommerce code on [CodePlex](https://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Models/Catalog/ProductDetailsModel.cs), the `ProductDetailModel` has a submodel `AddToCartModel` which in turn has a member `ProductId`. You should be able to use this field to fill you GA variable with it, like this: `ecomm_prodid:'<%#this.AddToCart.ProductId%>';`. The same should apply to the price, using `ecomm_productvalue:'<%#this.ProductPrice.Price%>';`

Comment: hi, I added the code: ecomm_prodid:'<%#this.AddToCart.ProductId%>'
ecomm_totalvalue:'<%#this.ProductPrice.Price%>' but it didn't work.  Maybe I have to put it in the script and then assign it to a variable and then use that variable in ecomm_prodid ?

Comment: What happens? Do you get a JS error? Does it write out the value?

Comment: a colleague tested it for me..she said it didn't work... said  it should appear like :
ecomm_prodid: "13784", i.e. actual id of product.
        ecomm_pagetype: "product", i.e. actual name of page.
        ecomm_totalvalue: 106.79  i.e. actual value.
so an actual value is displayed ... not the name of a string..

Comment: Sounds like it's just a matter of syntax then, probably you need to use `<%= this.ProductPrice.Price %>` with the "=" instead of "#". If you have a programmer available she should be able to figure it out - sorry this kind of remote debugging without actually getting a look at the code is pretty hard.

Comment: Product page I am adding it to: http://northseaworkwear.com/dewalt-apprentice-honey-sb-safety-boot-work-boots- View Source - at the very bottom of the page.  <%= this.ProductPrice.Price %> comes up instead of a dynamic equivalent of <%= this.ProductPrice.Price %>. price should be a number...

Comment: Are you maybe using using MVC with Razor, not WebForms? Then it would be `@Model.ProductPrice.Price`

Comment: nopCommerce is MVC yes.  I added @Model.ProductPrice.Price and it wouldn't load the page

Comment: MVC has different ViewEngines with different syntax though. I'm sorry but all i can do is guess without seeing the code, and right now i'm out of ideas.

Answer (score -2):

We are also using the nopcommerce3.80 what is the code to be added to get product id a